# How to render locals into JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, sails.js

I was taking a look at the sails generator code, and I noticed that they are rendering locals into the package.json file with <%= variableName %>.

How do you do this? Is this some kind of special module? Is this an ejs thing?  I've noticed Yeoman generators do the same thing.

[here's the sails code](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-generate-generator/blob/master/templates/package.json)

Answer (score 1):

Answer: Use lodash or underscore templating to render the variables.